# Eager Loading using Include does not show all records but one

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using EF Core and DB first approach in my WebAPI project.

I have the following auto-generated model class for StoreLocation:

```
 public partial class StoreLocation
{
    public StoreLocation()
    {
        Sales = new HashSet<Sales>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? NumberOfStaff { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Sales> Sales { get; set; }
}
```

And a Sales class:

```
public partial class Sales
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal? SalesPrice { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public int? StoreLocation { get; set; }

}
```

Then I have a method to get a StoreLocation based on an id with all its sales like this:

```
        [HttpGet("StoreWithSales/{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<StoreLocation>>> GetStoreWithSales(int id)
    {

        return await _context.StoreLocation.Where(s => s.Id == id).Include(store => store.Sales).ToListAsync();
    }
```

I use eager loading by using Include(). My problem is that when I run the api and fire this call, I only get the first item which does not have an ending "]"

See my result from the browser here:

```
[{"id":1,"locationName":"Copenhagen","description":"Assimilated multi-tasking secured line","numberOfStaff":2,"sales":[{"id":2,"salesPrice":47.80,"productType":"Socks","storeLocation":1
```

The rest is missing, why and where is it? When I tried to debug, I could see that that all the sales records are actually loaded but not returned in the browser. Thanks for any hints!

**EDIT:**

When I try to fire this particular call in Postman I get: `Could not get any response`.

In the browser I test by `https://localhost:XXXXX/api/sales/storeWithSales/2` it sometimes shows what I posted above and sometimes the browser page is blank. In the console is the following error: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Other GET calls where I simply retrieve all values from a table work with no issue and the error above from console is not present. I tried in Chrome and IE 11

**EDIT 2:** In Firefox I get this: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object at line 1 column 173 of the JSON data API response` so it seems like the server generates json with syntax error?

Comment: Looks like EF fetched all the data, but the JSON is getting truncated somewhere.  Perhaps run the API with PostMan or Fiddler?

Comment: What is your "result from the browser"? Is that what's being output in the HTML source, what you're seeing in the console window, what? It would probably be helpful to see your actual JS code as well.

Comment: You should map your entity to DTO. That fixes your problem.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1240) related?

Comment: @GertArnold - yep! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that JSON gets truncated, try to ignore reference loops like below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    );
}
```

Refer to https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1240